# What is the name of this flower

Tags: identification, flowers

I had this flowers a few years ago but I don't know what it is called so I don't know how to look for it now. Can anyone help identifying it.
This is the only photo I have

[image]

Comment: Claire, could you please add a few details (see the tag information for [tag:identification]), e.g. whether this is an indoor or outdoor plant or how big the flowers are.

Comment: It is an outdoor plant and the flowers are small. Thank you

Comment: Is the leaf we see in the foreground the foliage of this plant? And what part of the world was this plant growing in? What time of year did it flower in terms of the month/s? How tall was the plant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Lewisia - quite possibly the one shown here (Sunset Strain). They must have excellent drainage and full sun. Hardy to Zone 5 in the US. [-[image: (Lewisia 'Sunset Strain']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAyvc.jpg)